# Problema al hacer validar un botón radio con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, radio

Tengo un problema al intentar validar estos botones tipo radio. Quisiera que al seleccionar alguno y presionar continuar me muestre un `alert()`, pero no lo logro:

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, soy nuevo en esto.

**Acá mi HTML:**

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radios1">
    HTML-CSS
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radios2">
    JavaScript
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios3" value="option3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radios3">
    Ambos
  </label>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="mostrar()">Confirmar</button>
```

**Acá mi JavaScript:**

```js
let servicio = document.getElementsByName(servicio);
function mostrar() {
  switch (servicio) {
    case servicio.value:
      alert("Ha seleccionado HTML-CSS");
      break;

    case servicio.value:
      alert("Ha seleccionado JavaScript");
      break;

    case servicio.value:
      alert("Ha seleccionado un servicio completo.");
      break;

    default:
      alert("Por favor, seleccione un servicio.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero se debe obtener todos los elementos tipo radio y el botón que ejecutará la función que verificará si algún radio fue seleccionado o no. `.checked` retornará `true` si el radio ha sido seleccionado, en caso contrario, retornará `false`.

```js
// obtener los elementos
let servicio1 = document.getElementById("radios1"),
  servicio2 = document.getElementById("radios2"),
  servicio3 = document.getElementById("radios3"),
  confirmar = document.getElementById("confirmar");
  
// funcion para ejecutar el alert
function alertar() {
  if (!servicio1.checked && !servicio2.checked && !servicio3.checked) alert("Por favor, seleccione un servicio");
  if (servicio1.checked) alert("Ha seleccionado HTML-CSS");
  if (servicio2.checked) alert("Ha seleccionado JavaScript");
  if (servicio3.checked) alert("Ha seleccionado un servicio completo");
}

// evento click en el botón
confirmar.onclick = ()=>{
  alertar();
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radios1">
     HTML-CSS
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios2" value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radios2">
     JavaScript
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios3" value="option3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radios3">
     Ambos
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <button id="confirmar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" >Confirmar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Puede funcionar, pero realizando algunos cambios

Tu solución funcionará si se aplican los siguientes cambios:

Cambiando esta línea:

```js
let servicio = document.getElementsByName(servicio);
```

Por esta otra:

```js
let servicio = document.getElementsByName("servicio");
```

Porque `servicio` será tomado como una variable (además, de no estar previamente inicializada) en lugar de tomarse como una cadena `"servicio"`.

En la estructura `switch`, en lugar de utilizar:

```js
switch (servicio) {
  case servicio.value:
    // Intrucciones.
    break;

  ...
}
```

Cámbiala por esta otra:

```js
switch (true) {
  case servicio[0].checked:
    // Intrucciones.
    break;

  ...
}
```

Además, `servicio` no es un elemento o un nodo, es una lista nodos `[object NodeList]`.

#### Ejemplo completo y verificable

En el siguiente ejemplo, he tomado todo el código que has publicado, pero, lo he modificado con las recomendaciones mencionadas anteriormente en esta publicación:

```js
let servicio = document.getElementsByName("servicio");

function mostrar() {
  switch (true) {
    case servicio[0].checked:
      alert("Ha seleccionado HTML-CSS")
      break

    case servicio[1].checked:
      alert("Ha seleccionado JavaScript")
      break

    case servicio[2].checked:
      alert("Ha seleccionado un servicio completo.")
      break

    default:
      alert("Por favor, seleccione un servicio.")

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radios1">
     HTML-CSS
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radios2">
     JavaScript
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="servicio" id="radios3" value="option3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radios3">
     Ambos
    </label>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="mostrar()">Confirmar</button>
```

Note que en la estructura **`switch`** he cambiado esta:

```js
case servicio.value:
```

Por esta otra:

```js
case servicio[0].checked:
```

Ya que, en caso de que el usuario la seleccione devolverá `true`.